# F# light weight scripting enviorment

Tags: c#, .net, f#, f#-interactive

Im using F# to do a little scripting for automating tasks on our servers here. I would really love to have a light weight environment i could install on the servers themselves to give me FSI and auto-completion

Thank you

---

Just to clarify Im looking for something like PowerShell ISE but with VS auto completion

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this exists yet, would be great if someone could implement one though :)

Comment: I heard somewhere that the F# team are shying away from making FSI itself too powerful - there is auto completion in fsx files, and they want your scripts to be permanent rather than a bunch of stuff typed on a command prompt. So maybe you want a remote controlled FSI instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any complete project that includes completion, but [Funtasticolor](http://funtasticolor.codeplex.com/) looks interesting.
A support for auto-completion and tool tips could be added using this [simple command line tool](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=fsharp%20intellisense%20tool&referringTitle=Home).